Convexity iff convexity on any line, why we need to restrict $x \in D$
There is theorem states the following,

$f \colon D \subset\Bbb R^n\to \Bbb R$ is convex if and only if for any $x \in D$, $v \in \Bbb R^n$, the function $g\colon \operatorname{dom}g =\{t\mid x+tv \in D\}\subset \Bbb{R}\to \Bbb R$, $g(t) = f(x+tv)$ is convex.

I konw how to prove the theorem, but confused why we need to restrict $x \in D$. Here is my proof, it seems for any $x \in \Bbb{R^n}$,$v \in \Bbb R^n$, the above statement always hold.
($\Leftarrow$) first prove for any $x \in \Bbb{R^n}$,$v \in \Bbb R^n$, $\operatorname{dom}g=\{t\mid x+tv \in D\}$ is convex. $\forall t_1, t_2 \dom g$, $\forall \alpha \in[0,1]$, $\alpha t_1+(1-\alpha)t_2 \in \dom g$ (Since we have $x+t_1v\in D$, $x+t_2v\in D$, $\alpha(x+t_1v) +(1-\alpha)(x+t_2v) \in D$).
Then prove $g$ is convex
($\Rightarrow$) Similarly, we first have to show $D$ is convex, $\forall x_1, x_2 \in D$, $\forall \alpha \in[0,1]$, we need to show $\alpha x_1+ (1-\alpha)x_2 \in D$, the trick is choose $x=x_1, v=x_2-x_1$.
Both directions do not rely on $x \in D$

You're right, the   theorem would work just as well without the restriction $x \in D$ (as long as you don't mind having
functions with empty domains being called convex). There's nothing special about $x$ in the line $\{x+tv: t \in \mathbb R\}$, it's just an arbitrary point on the line which is taken as the origin ($t=0$).  If that line intersects $D$, you might as well take it to be a point in $D$, but there's no reason it has to be in $D$.

Yes, but even if $x \in D$, we can still not guarantee the domain of $g$ is not empty coz we may encounter cases when $D$ is empty?

If $x \in D$, then the domain is not empty because it contains $x$.
